# Using SQLAlchemy `and_` with MagicMock

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, magicmock

I have a SQLAlchemy call that I am trying to mock.

```
Model.query.filter(and_(Model.id.in_(some_ids), Model.other_id != None)).all()
```

I am using MagicMock to mock this call and give it a return value. The issue I am having is when I add the `and_`.

Setting a return value for a call that does not have `and_` is as simple as:

```
mock_model_class.query.filter().all.return_value = some_value
```

When I try to mock the `and_` I get an error from SQLAlchemy.

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'> instead`

I have tried different variations, to no avail... such as:

`mock_model_class.query.filter().and_().all.return_value`
`mock_model_class.query.filter(and_).all.return_value`

Is there some syntax to this that I am missing?

Comment: This is a good argument for making query executor function - so that its easy to mock out, e.g.: `def query_all(model, *filters): return Model.query.filter(*filters).all()` something like that anyway.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mock `sqlalchemy.and_`. The reasoning is that this is called before your mocked filter is executed.